# Ubuntu 18.04 and GNOME, make Windows Controls clickables at top left corner

Tags: gnome, 18.04, ubuntu-gnome

Is there a plugin for GNome to make the top left most pixel click the Close button?

I have already moved the Windows Contols to left, but when I do a fast "move top left" to close the window, it does not trigger any action, and I have to move a few pixels down to click it.